# UISegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:forState: not working well with font

Tags: ios, attributes, uisegmentedcontrol, uifont

I have a UISegmentedControl that I'm trying to customize, and I'm having two problems :

This is my code :

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Book" size:14.f],
                                 UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor]};
    [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = @{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Medium" size:14.f],
                                     UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor redColor]};
    [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

1) The UISegmentedControl reacts well for the UIControlStateNormal but for the forState:UIControlStateSelected, the color works but not the font. FYI, the font exists because if I switch "Gotham-Book" and "Gotham-Medium" for UIControlStateNormal, I see the difference.

2) Before I've set the font for the UIControlStateNormal, the text was vertically aligned, but now it's not anymore. How could I change the textInsets ?

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score -1):

On IOS 7 use NSFontAttributeName, NSForegroundColorAttributeName and NSShadowAttributeName (if needed),

For backward compatibility I using both variants, like:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Book" size:14.f],
                             UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                             UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor],
                             NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Book" size:14.f],
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
};
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```